# As simple as saving a Hashset in the SharedPrefs

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, persistence, hashset

I was trying to write a simple method for my android application. This method should find an integer [0-49] that isn't contained in a HashSet. Afterward should save the HashSet in the sharedPrefs using the putStringSet() method. Below I provide the code I have written.

```
    HashSet aHashSet;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int id;

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    aHashSet = (HashSet) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("aHashSet", null);

    if (aHashSet == null)
        aHashSet = new HashSet();


    for (id = 0; id < 50; ++id) {
        if (aHashSet.contains(id))
            continue;
        else {
            aHashSet.add(id);
            break;
        }

    }


    Log.d("myClassName", String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("aHashSet", aHashSet).commit()));

    return id;
```

I have checked the logs every time I add something to the set and save it in the shredPrefs I get a true (as a successful) commit. While this worked fine while the app was running, After the application was closed the HashSet wasn't saved correctly, and the starting number was always 0.

So I tried to debug this, I thought that I'll use a String and I will append the numbers to it and then save it, in order to check if the problem is that I cannot save the Hashset correctly, so I add this logic as below.

```
    HashSet<String> aHashSet;
    int id;

    aHashSet = (HashSet) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("aHashSet", null);
    String checkingString = sharedPreferences.getString("cs","");

    if (aHashSet == null)
        aHashSet = new HashSet();


    for (id=0;id<50;++id){
        if(aHashSet.contains(String.valueOf(id)))
            continue;
        else{
            aHashSet.add(String.valueOf(id));
            break;
        }

    }

    checkingString+= id;
    Log.d("myClassName",String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("aHashSet",aHashSet).commit()));
    Toast.makeText(this, checkingString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("cs",checkingString).commit();
    return id;
```

Now what I was expecting to see was: the checkingString to be appended and saved correctly, but the HashSet to lose the added values every time the app is restarted. **However, now everything worked as it should**, the HashSet was saved and restored correctly every time the app was restarted. Can someone explain to me how is this possible? the only change I did was to add another string to the sharedPrefs, how could this influence the HashSet? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. For this type of problem I have made two function for storing and retrieving multiple value using Hashmap

**Store data into preference**

```
public static void storePreference(HashMap<String, String> parameters) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ManageMyAppsApplication.sharedPref
                .edit();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = parameters.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();
            editor.putString((String) pairs.getKey(), (String) pairs.getValue());
        }
        editor.commit();
    }
```

**Retrieving data from preference**

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getPreference(String[] keys) {
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String key : keys) {
            parameters.put(key,
                    ManageMyAppsApplication.sharedPref.getString(key, null));
        }
        return parameters;
    }
```

Comment: I just want an explanation why this works like that. My method works as well